# DataSource (object) not bind to textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net, data-binding, navigation, visual-studio-2015

I am new to VB and visual studio. I followed the online tutorial to do the binding. But I can not click the Text property of the advanced binding page, as following. I am not sure **what information is necessary to debug**. So, I just post the creenshot here. Any questions. please let me know.
The code of the class used as the datasource:

```
Public Class MIConfig
    Public m_name As String
    Public m_primary As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal primary As Integer)
        m_name = name
        m_primary = primary
    End Sub
End Class


'TextBox1
'
Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 193)
Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(120, 26)
Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 3
```

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

**Why down-voted, please leave a comment or solution or anything?**
Otherwise, down-voting cannot help improve the society.

[image]

Comment: Mark you class as DataSource. _Advanced binding(window in your screenshot) -> Binding -> Add project DataSource -> Object -> Select your class_

Comment: @Fabio See the updated pic, it seems that my TextBox is not bindable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Mark your class as DataSource
   `Advanced binding`(window in your screenshot) -> `Binding` -> `Add project DataSource` -> `Object` -> Select your class
2. Select property of your class in the `Binding` which you want use for data-binding
   Property will be bounded to the TextBox.Text property by default

For data-binding you need to have properties in your class, at this moment your class contains only fields

```vb
Public Class MIConfig
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Primary As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal primary As Integer)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Primary = primary
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you have trouble to use data-binding through Designer, try it in the code

```vb
Public Class MyForm
    Private _BindingModel As MIConfig

    Public Sub New(model As MIConfig)
        Me.InitializeComponent()

        _BindingModel = model

       TextBox1.DataBinding.Add("Text", _BindingModel, "m_name", True)

    End Sub

End Class
```